# Node js mongodb database connection error failed to connect to server

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb

> C:\mynodeprojects\test>node app Sever start on 300 failed to connect
>   to server [localhost:27017] on first connect [MongoError: geta ddrinfo
>   ENOENT localhost:27017]

Package : -

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "simple test app",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "hukam thakur",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.16.2",
    "mongodb": "^2.2.33",
    "mongoose": "^4.10.8",
    "sudo": "^1.0.3"
  }
}
```

DB Connection here: -

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var mongoURI = "mongodb://localhost:27017/test";
var MongoDB = mongoose.connect(mongoURI).connection;
MongoDB.on('error', function(err) { console.log(err.message); });
MongoDB.once('open', function() {
  console.log("mongodb connection open");
});
```

Comment: Seriously? Show your code, please.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take a minute to read on [How to ask a question.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Could you please tell me, Where I'm doing wrong?

Comment: iagnostic data capture with directory 'C:/data/db/diagnostic.data'
2017-11-13T18:27:43.800+0530 I NETWORK  [thread1] waiting for connections on por
t 27017

Comment: I experienced this same issue, in my case the DB didn't exist. I created it previously but it seemed to have not saved to persistent memory somehow. I recreated my database via the command line then I was able to connect. For troubleshooting you can try accessing any members of the database in a more manual way, like through the command line.

Answer (score 3):

Please Try this code it's work for me :

```
var database,

ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectID,

MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient,

url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/test',

connection=MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {  
  if (err) throw err;
  database=db;
});
```

Then write query like (eg for find `uniqueId`)-

```
database.collection("users").findOne({_id:new ObjectId(userId)}, function(err, res) { 
 if (err) console.log(err);
   console.log(res);
});
```

Comment: have u use this command for ubuntu  to allow mongodb access  -


 **sudo ufw allow 27017**

Comment: Server listening on port 3000      ^
MongoError: failed to connect to server [localhost:27017] on first connect [MongoError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017]

Comment: Mongo port default 27017. You can access mongo in node when you allow ufw command. It provide access to mongo database

Comment: iagnostic data capture with directory 'C:/data/db/diagnostic.data'
2017-11-13T18:27:43.800+0530 I NETWORK  [thread1] waiting for connections on por
t 27017

Comment: which OS you have used?

Comment: Mongo Database configure step in ubuntu server

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-mongodb-on-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: Thanks Bro for support !.  The Problem is the Data/DB folder permission. When I set full access to that folder then it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

use 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost